# Why do mouse wheels stop working correctly with time?

Tags: mouse, wireless-mouse, mouse-wheel

I noticed that I need to change my wireless mouse every few months because of the same reason: mouse wheel starts to get more and more unresponsive as time passes. I was wondering how does the mouse wheel work in the wireless mouse and why does it degrade? How is it possible for a electronic device with no moving parts to behave like this? I thought it's because of dirt & dust but it's not because I tried cleaning the mouse and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Changed the batteries?

Comment: I've never experienced any issue with mouse wheel using mice for several years (I've a logitech anywhere now). What type of mouse do you have issues with? Do you use them in special environment (high humidity,  dust...)?

Comment: Of course, and I`m still using the old battery in the new mouse

Comment: Unless you bought a cheapo mouse, they ought to last a decade or more. Assume contamination.... though I just realised you said you put the old batteries in the new mouse... :/

Answer (score 1):

They should not be degrading that fast. I've used mice for over 5 years with no issues. I recommend going with another brand or model if your buying the same one every time.

> The scroll wheel at the front of the mouse is mounted on a switch mechanism that detects both how much it's rotated and whether you've pressed it (it functions like the central button of a conventional mouse). Rotations of the scroll wheel can be detected in a variety of different ways. Some mice use potentiometers (broadly, variable resistors), similar to the volume control on a radio but able to turn around multiple times. Others use various kinds of rotary switches or optical (rotary) encoders to convert analog wheel movements to digital signals.   http://www.explainthatstuff.com/computermouse.html